# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I received this error:

```
Server Error in Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization' could not be loaded.
```

After I received this error, I changed the property of `system.web.DataVisualization.dll` is `Copy Local= true`, and this dll is also in the bin directory. but the error remains constant.

What should I have to do to get rid of this error.

Comment: what is your .net version

Answer (score 2):

Change version of `System.Web.DataVisualization` in web.config file to project framework version.

Ex.

```
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0
```

to

```
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0
```

Make sure to change the all equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check that your project is using a relatively recent version of .Net (4.0 or newer).

See  **Target Framework** under **properties** for your project:

[image: Project properties]

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same error. Downloading and running the .exe to install the required assemblies, from Microsoft website solved it. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422%20